# What Task and Time Management tools are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, task-management, time-management

Is there a package to install in a server for task/time management?
I want to create activities and add milestones to those activities, maybe it can have  graphics reports too.

I'd like to install it in a server and to use it from other PCs, not local. (a web interfase).

Maybe something like [Klock](http://www.getklok.com/)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Tine 2.0](http://www.tine20.org/) is an option, it has a very good calendar and task module. [Horde Groupware](http://horde.org/) can be good as well. If you need project management, [PHProjekt](http://phprojekt.com/) may be worth a look.

Comment: yes, I've checked the demo and I think Tine or PHProjekt will work, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

How about Gnome Planner?
http://live.gnome.org/Planner

[image]

Another one is TaskJuggler: http://www.taskjuggler.org
[image]

If you already use KOffice then KPlato is there for you: http://www.kde.org/applications/office/kplato/

Last but not least, for only task management there is http://ginatrapani.github.com/todo.txt-cli/
One of my favorite, a command line utility, really awesome!

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion:

TSheets [time tracker](http://www.tsheets.com/workforce-management.html) - the reports generated in this app are extremely helpful

Comment: Is this spam? Are you affiliated with the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [RationalPlan](http://www.rationalplan.com/). The are several products within the suite for different needs and it can also be found on Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Is this spam? Are you affiliated with the app?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend [super productivity](https://super-productivity.com/). I

Quoting from the readme, the features include:

- **Full control over your data**, no tracking, no user accounts, no cloud
- Sub Tasks
- Time Tracking
- Sexy global bookmark bar to add quick links, project related files and even commands and applications
- Sexy note functionality with custom reminders
- Pomodoro timer
- 'Take a break' reminder
- Full Keyboard interaction
- Different Themes!
- Mobile support
- Repeatable tasks for daily chores
- Configurable and automatable Jira integration for:

  - searching and adding tasks from jira
  - creating (local/personal) sub tasks for your jira tickets
  - setting transitions aka setting tickets to in progress or done
  - automatic notifications once an issue in your list has changed or been commented on jira => no messy email notifications required any more
- Configurable and automatable Git integration for:

  - searching and adding tasks from git
  - automatic notifications once an issue in your list has changed or been commented
- Export your time sheets to Google Sheets (optional of course)
- Sync data between multiple instances (optional of course)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using 8work [time tracking software](https://8work.co/), try 14 days free. complete with monitor screenshoot with random time.

[image: time tracking with screenshoot monitor]